# Configure spatial index using Query Entities in Apache Ignite's NodeJS Thin Client

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, indexing, ignite

I am trying to configure a geospatial index for performant intersect querying on an Ignite Cache. I am able to set the field as queryable, and have set the index using the recommended syntax `.setIndexes(new QueryIndex("columnName")`.

However, when I perform an "EXPLAIN SELECT" SqlFieldsQuery on the cache I am seeing `.__SCAN` instead of the indexed column. I believe this means it is scanning the entire cache instead of using the index, but could not find documentation on this.

```
'SELECT\n' +
    '    "__Z0"."EXAMPLESTRING" AS "__C0_0",\n' +
    '    "__Z0"."EXAMPLESPATIAL" AS "__C0_1"\n' +
    'FROM "mySpatialGeometryCache"."EXTENDEDPOINT" "__Z0"\n' +
    '    /* mySpatialGeometryCache.EXTENDEDPOINT.__SCAN_ */\n' +
    'WHERE INTERSECTS("__Z0"."EXAMPLESPATIAL", ?1)'
```

Here is the `queryEntity` I have configured:

```js
new QueryEntity()
      .setValueTypeName("ExtendedPoint")
      .setFields([
        new QueryField("exampleString", "java.lang.String"),
        new QueryField("exampleSpatial", "java.lang.String"),
      ])
      .setIndexes(
        new Array(new QueryIndex("geo",QueryIndex.INDEX_TYPE.GEOSPATIAL))
      )
  );
```

I am not getting any errors or console warnings, and I am able to query the exampleSpatial field just fine, but I want to ensure that an index is being used so that it performs best when the cache is at a higher volume.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this guide](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/indexes) when creating indexes.

Look in the INDEXES [system view](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/system-views#indexes) to see that you've indexed the correct fields.

Use the [EXPLAIN](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/sql-tuning#using-the-explain-statement) command to see which indexes the optimizer considers useful for a given query.

Comment: Thanks for assisting! I have been referring to that guide and I saw that the query indexes were being set through an array. I have altered my approach to match it as close as I can, but to no avail.


I entered the system view and was able to confirm the queryable columns that my query entity was configured with, but when I searched for indexes in my table it came up empty. 


I am not sure why some aspects of my query entity are impacting the table, while others aren't. Please see original post for revised QueryIndex initialization.